# Getting LCD message through IPMI form Dell Server (Poweredge R710)

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I'm exploring the IPMI interface (using `ipmitool` on ubuntu 11.10, remotely over LAN) and can perform various operations however, I can't view the status message displayed on the LCD.

`ipmitool` supports `delloem lcd` subcommands. These subcommands unfortunately primarily only allow me to set data to the lcd, but I can't read from the lcd.

The message currently displayed on the LCD relates to the loss of power redundancy (Dell orange error). For testing purposes I manually removed the redundant power supply and have been trying to read the message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This may not get you the text off the LCD, but have you tried the `chassis` and `power` subcommands?  It's been a while since I had Dell equipment, but I believe one of these has power supply status information.

Alternatively you can install the OpenManage SNMP agent and query this information (and a lot more) via SNMP without having to parse `ipmitool`'s output yourself.

Comment: They do provide power status information, however I am explicitly interested in what the LCD is showing.